# How do I use the analysis output of a UCI engine?

Tags: analysis, engines, uci

I'm trying to analyze some of my games with the Stockfish UCI engine.  I'd like to make sure I'm interpreting the output correctly.  Using this screenshot as an example.

[image: stockfish UCI analysis output]

Can someone explain to me all of the output? Such as.

What does this line tell me?

> 20 [-1.13]  7.c3 Bg4 8.h3 Bxf3 9.Qxf3 bxa4 (8.39)

What does this line tell me?

> [-1.33] Depth: 27/40 Nodes: 550933K (4130 kn/s) Time: 133.41 s
>   NPS: 4129627 Hash: ---- Load: ---- TB hits: ---- Current: c3 (1/25)

If the first number is centipawns why does it continue to analyze positions that seem to give me a worse position?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is showing you the results of the analysis for each depth it gets to, sometimes more than once per depth (I think those are upper/lower bound scores, actually). So at depth 20 it thought the best move was -1.13 pawns, and at depth 27 it now knows it's really -1.33 pawns (according to its evaluation).

I like to use the multi-pv setting (click the up spinner next to V++ to increase the number of root moves to analyze), which gives you a good overall perspective of your different options (you can compare `c3` and `Nc3`, for example).

Comment: Just to clarify the two depth numbers, the first number is the depth - that is, the minimum number of plies that the engine has examined in all lines (factoring in A/B pruning).  The second number is "seldepth" or selective depth.  This is the deepest that the engine has calculated.  See [chessprograming](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Depth) for more info.

Comment: What's the 8.39 at the end of this line: `20 [-1.13] 7.c3 Bg4 8.h3 Bxf3 9.Qxf3 bxa4 (8.39)`

Comment: @SnowCrash that's the time so far, I believe.